# What's interpolation and extrapolation in the context of ROS?

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [FAQ](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/FAQ#How_does_tf_deal_with_interpolation_and_extrapolation.3F), it's written

> #### How does `tf` deal with interpolation and extrapolation?

> Our experimentation has shown that interpolation is fine, but extrapolation almost always ends up becoming more of a problem than a solution. If you are having trouble with data being ready before transforms are available I suggest using the `tf::MessageFilter` class in `tf`. It will queue incoming data until transforms are available. Having tried allowing "just a little" extrapolation, waiting for accurate data to be available has proved a much better approach.

First of all, what, in general, is interpolation and extrapolation in the context of ROS? I understood it's something to do with data, but could someone give me a **complete** explanation of these concepts?

Furthermore, the excerpt above states:

> Our experimentation has shown that interpolation is fine

Fine in which sense, to do what? Why is it fine? How does ROS support interpolation? Which experiments did "they" use?

> but extrapolation almost always ends up becoming more of a problem than a solution

Why does extrapolation almost always ends up becoming a problem? And why `tf::MessageFilter` would be a "solution" to extrapolation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287855/what%27s-interpolation-and-extrapolation-in-the-context-of-ros?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Interpolation and extrapolation are used in the standard mathematical context.

https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/extrapolation-and-interpolation

You can find many other good explanations by searching online.

Interpolating between measurements does not amplify measurement noise like extrapolation does.

MessageFilters provide a way to hold data until the transform information is available so you don't need to extrapolate.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-07**:
I specifically asked in the context of ROS. I know e.g. what is "interpolation" of a set of points, etc.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
TF deals with coordinate data with a time dimension attached. Interpolation and extrapolation are quite clearly defined in those contexts. There is nothing special about ROS here.

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-08**:
I will never accept these answers, which are not answers to my question at all!

**Comment by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on 2018-04-08**:
@gvdhoorn "Interpolation and extrapolation are quite clearly defined in those contexts"???

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
There's two dimensions to TF:

1. time (ie: instants)
2. space (ie: poses)

We're all happy to help, but what is unclear *precisely* about how time and space are interpolated?